# What is the 'best practice' method of using common one-to-many associations when data modelling with Grails

Tags: database-design, grails

Take this example:

The application contains Domain classes for different types of contact, e.g.

Manager, ShopSteward, Pilot, BaseballCoach, etc.

They are all individual classes, and thus all have their own seperate tables in the database.

A common requirement is to record multiple email addresses.  In order to avoid duplicated code, I would create a @Validatable class in src/groovy called EmailAddress that contains the emailAddress of course, along with an optional label for that address.

Now in order to allow all those different Domain classes to have multiple email addresses recorded against them is it best to create new Domain classes that extend EmailAddress and link back to the owner side of the relationship?

E.g.

```
class ManagerEmailAddress extends EmailAddress {
  static belongsTo = [Manager]
}
```

& add

```
 hasMany = [emails:ManagerEmailAddress]
```

to the Manager class? Or is it better to have a single EmailAddresses table with lots of discriminators in order to identify the owning entity?

Thanks for your comments/replies in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicating same structure over different tables/classes is rarely a good idea (table-per-concrete-class would reduce code duplication here). And alternate database relationship with discriminator is a signal that the parent tables should be merged.

So, it might make sense to extract a common superclass like `Person` or `Contact` and connect the `Emails` to that class.